# Mp3s Having Different Bit Rates in Windows & Software

Tags: mp3

While searching through my Mp3 library, I noticed that some Mp3s had a bit rate above 192kbps.  I activated an encoding software and dragged/dropped these Mp3s into it so that I could encode  them to 192kbps.  After doing so the software showed me that these Mp3s had bot rates ranging between 34kbps and 112kbps.  On checking the size, the Mp3s are around 8 to 10MBs.  Can someone explain this difference and what should I do ?

Thank you,

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Some concepts of MP3

`MP3 file structure`

MP3 file consists of series of MP3 "frames", each of which can be encoded with a different bit rate. Hence it is possible that first frame is encoded at 128kbps where as next one could be 192kbps.

`CBR and VBR MP3`

Given this, there are two types of MP3 files 
(a) Constant bit-rate (CBR) MP3 - bit rate is same over the entire duration of file. 
(b) Variable bit-rate (VBR) MP3 - bit rate can vary across MP3 frames in the file.

Based on your question, your file looks like a variable bit rate MP3 file.

`Average bit rate`

To calculate average bit-rate of a MP3 file by following equation = (file size in bytes * 8) / (duration of file in seconds).

`When to re-encode to reduce size of a MP3 file?`

Using this average bit-rate, you can decide whether it is worth re-encoding or not. Usually 128 kbps CBR gives good compression at reasonable quality.